# How to get the array from string staring from @ and end with space in the string

Tags: php, regex

How do I get an array from the below string?
I need what is  between `@` and `space`.

```
Gold star @RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2 nice James @72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53 for @DoxBay
```

I am using the explode php function

```
$output=explode("@",$title);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably regex.
This captures what is between a `@` and a space.
Since the last word does not have a space after it we can either add a space to the string or change the pattern. I choose to add a space.

```
$str = "Gold star @RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2 nice James @72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53 for @DoxBay";
preg_match_all("/\@(.*?)\s/", $str . " ", $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "@RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2 "
    [1]=>
    string(30) "@72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53 "
    [2]=>
    string(8) "@DoxBay "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "DoxBay"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/RNM2P

Comment: It could be `@\S+(?=\s)` or depended on requirements `@\S+` only.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you will want to use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to create an array of all matches from your string.

This will take your string and compare it against your pattern.  It will place the the results you are looking for in the second element of the matches array.

Like so:

```
$str = 'Gold star @RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2 nice James @72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53 for @DoxBay ';

preg_match_all('/@(.*?)\s/', $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[1]);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => RPXIeDIWVuTHFWGkaWbJEvv0KFk2
    [1] => 72oCu3zBCHQzS5fiY3KNFCWkgA53
    [2] => DoxBay
)
```

Comment: @revo Thanks for the tip.. I like the `@\S+`  ~Cheers!